# How to set a Code-based rectangle's style from a XAML resource file by code

Tags: c#, xaml

I created a resource file as 'Style' which sets the fillcolor and border of a rectangle.
In 'code' I create a rectangle which is dynamic in size as it's being set by another rectangle size.

What I want is to create the code-based rectangle and have its style set by the resource xaml-file.

How can I do this other then to set it by code.
If possible I don't want to use XamlReader.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a style that would apply to *all* `Rectangle`s, by specifying only the target type and no `x:Key`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: when I got time for this :P I'll try to figure out of this is possible for us.